# Proving that $\sigma_7(n) = \sigma_3(n) + 120 \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \sigma_3(m)\sigma_3(n-m)$ without using modular forms?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-forms, divisor-sum

This problem appears as a (starred!) exercise in D. Zagier's notes on modular forms. I have to admit that I have no idea how to do it.

Here,  $\sigma_k(n) =\sum_{d\mid n} d^k$, as usual.

This identity is traditionally obtained by using the fact that the space $M_8(\text{SL}_2(\mathbf Z))$ of modular forms of weight $8$ and level $1$ is $1$-dimensional, and contains both $E_4^2$ and $E_8$ ($E_k$ the Eisenstein series of weight $k$). Using this, it's a piece of cake (simply a matter of comparing coefficients).

Without using modular forms, though, I am stumped.

Comment: If your interested I can show you how to prove it using only some algebra, but it requires a lot of pain in the ass combinatorial manipulations.

Comment: @Ethan, sure, a pain in the ass combinatorial proof is exactly the sort of thing I would enjoy!

Comment: Alright I will start writing it, but you wont enjoy it lol.

Comment: @Ethan Haha, ok, thanks in advance. If you want to just sketch the argument, that could be fine as well.

Comment: not sure why the right hand side is number-theoretic multiplicative...It must be, as the left hand side is; anyway, show multiplicative, then show for $n=p$ prime and $n=p^k$

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, I thought about that, but it didn't lead me anywhere. I can neither show that the RHS is multiplicative, nor show that it equals $p^7$ when $n=p$... as bad as it gets, really ;)

Comment: @BrunoJoyal I can't remember exactly how it goes but I know that you first write: $$\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\sigma_3(m)\sigma_3(n-m)=\sum_{ax+by=n}_{(a,x,b,y)\in \mathbb{N^4}}a^3b^3$$ And then manipulate the sum on the right by splitting it up into special cases and making several combinatorial arguments. Here is a paper which proves your identity in an elementary manner as a corrolarry of a formula that is established using elementry techniques. Though this formula is much stronger then just what is needed to prove your specific identity. http://people.math.carleton.ca/~williams/papers/pdf/249.pdf

Comment: @Ethan Thanks for the reference!

Comment: @Ethan Modular forms are just what I use to resolve these kind of sums. I'd be interested to see a combinatorial proof though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually there is a purely elementary proof of this identity due to a lemma of Liouville in his work (1858)  (Liouville, J. Sur quelques formules générales qui peuvent être utiles dans la théorie des nombres). It would be helpful to understand his series of articles there (I found the third one very good) or to immitate the reproduction of proof in http://www.numdam.org/article/JTNB_2006__18_1_223_0.pdf to prove the following elementary fact on arithmetic functions (or "order theory"):
If $$f:\ \mathbb{Z}^4\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$$ is a function such that
$$f(a,b,x,y)-f(x,y,a,b)=f(-a,-b,x,y)-f(x,y,-a,-b)$$ for any integers $a,b,c,d$, then we have the following identity for any positive integer $n$
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{ax+by=n,\\ a,b,x,y\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}}(f(a,b,x,-y)-f(a,-b,x,y)+f(a,a-b,x+y,y)-f(a,a+b,y-x,y)+f(b-a,b,x,x+y)-f(a+b,b,x,x-y))\\
=&\sum_{d|n}\ \sum_{x\in\mathbb{Z},0<x<d}(f(o,n/d,x,d)+f(n/d,0,d,x)+f(n/d,n/d,d-x,-x)-f(x,x-d,n/d,n/d)-f(x,d,0,n/d)-f(d,x,n/d,0)).
\end{aligned}$$
Now consider the function $$f(a,b,x,y)=xy^5+x^5y-2x^3 y^3$$ which is independent of $a,b$ and clearly satisfies the above condition. So we can apply the lemma above to write down the following identity. The LHS of it is 
$$\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{ax+by=n,\\ a,b,x,y\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}}(-2xy^5-2x^5 y+4x^3 y^3 +(x+y)y^5 + (x+y)^5y - 2(x+y)^3 y^3-(y-x)y^5-(y-x)^5y+ 2(y-x)^3 y^7+ x(x+y)^5+ x^5(x+y)-2x^3 (x+y)^3- x(x-y)^5- x^5(x-y)+ 2x^3(x-y)^3)\\
=&\sum_{ax+by=n,\\ a,b,x,y\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}}36x^3 y^3\\
=&36\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\sigma_3 (m)\sigma_3 (n-m).
\end{aligned}$$
and the RHS is simply
$$\sum_{d|n}\ \sum_{x\in\mathbb{Z},0<x<d}(xd^5+5x^2d^4-12x^3d^4+4x^4d^2+2x^5d).$$
Note that if we sum $x$ over $1$ to $d$ the result is the same, and we have the formula of sum of powers
$$S_p(d)=\sum_{k=1}^{d}k^p=\frac{1}{p+1}\sum_{j=0}^{p}(-1)^j {p+1\choose j}B_j d^{p+1-j},$$
In particular one has
$$\begin{aligned}
S_1(d)&=\frac{d^2+d}{2}\\
S_2(d)&=\frac{2d^3+3d^2+d}{6}\\
S_3(d)&=\frac{d^4+2d^3+d^2}{4}\\
S_4(d)&=\frac{6d^5+15d^4+10d^3-d}{30}\\
S_5(d)&=\frac{2d^6+6d^5+5d^4-d^2}{12}.
\end{aligned}$$
The RHS can be then simplified in terms of $S_i(d) $ ($1\leq i\leq 5$)into 
$$\sum_{d|n}\frac{3}{10}(d^7-d^3)=\frac{3}{10}(\sigma_7 (n)-\sigma_3 (n))$$
and thus from $LHS=RHS$ one concludes that
$$\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\sigma_3(m) \sigma_3(n-m)=\frac{1}{120}(\sigma_7(n)-\sigma_3(n)).$$
It is also interesting to note that similarly one can prove many identities arising from modular forms, more precisely from the linear dependence of elements in the algebra of modular forms of a certain weight, by using only combinatorial "A=B" tricks and "no analysis". For example, for weight $14$ one also has identities like
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\sigma_5(m) \sigma_7(n-m)&=\frac{1}{10080}(\sigma_{13}(n)+20\sigma_7(n)-21\sigma_5(n)\\
\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\sigma_3(m) \sigma_9(n-m)&=\frac{1}{2640}(\sigma_{13}(n)-11\sigma_9(n)+10\sigma_3(m)\\
\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\sigma(m) \sigma_{11}(n-m)&=\frac{1}{65520}(691\sigma_{13}(n)+2730(1-n)\sigma_{11}(n)-691\sigma(n)).
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: This is fine for a Liouville, Jacobi, or Ramanujan, but not for us mortals.

Comment: Amazing, thank you!